# How to make LI elements wrap in UL?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have two pretty similar examples,but LI behaves differently each time:

1)
[li element is not getting wrapped](https://codepen.io/adamssef/pen/JjYdGKW?editors=1100)

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="item">First</li>                 
  <li class="item">Sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssed</li>
  <li class="item">Third</li>
  <li class="item">Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
  .list {
   width:300px;
   background-color: lightblue;
   font-size: 50px;
  }
```

2) [li element gets wrapped](https://codepen.io/adamssef/pen/WNQvryN)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">First</li>                 
  <li class="item">Third very very long long long long long long lont </li>
  <li class="item">Third</li>
  <li class="item">Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.list {
  width:300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: `word-break:break-all;`

Comment: thanks. It works well indeed.